# Escaping issues for MySQL in node while creating database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to create a database using mysql module. However it fails when I use escape.

This works fine

```
return db.query('CREATE DATABASE dbdbdbdbdbd', []);
```

This however fails

```
return db.query('CREATE DATABASE ?', ['dbdbdbdbdbd']);
```

However since my database name is dependant on user input, I do not want to be using the statement without escaping it.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [`sqlstring`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlstring) npm package for preventing sql injection attaccks

```
return db.query(`CREATE DATABASE ${SqlString.escape(name)}`, []);
```